# Python list index error (student files)

Tags: python

I am having problem with a list for an averaging program, it says:

'line 20, in 
    nameletter = (letter[int(num)])
IndexError: list index out of range'

This is the part of the code:

```
    f2 = open("Classes" + "/Sorted/" + "Alphabetical.txt", "w")

letter = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

print(letter[num])

#Loop
while num <= 26:
    nameletter = (letter[int(num)])
    if os.path.exists("Classes" + "/" + nameletter + ".txt"):
        #Opening the students file
        f = open("Classes" + "/" + nameletter + ".txt")
        List = f.read().splitlines()
        f.close()
        #Writing data to the file
        f2.write(List[5] + " - score = " + List[6])
        f2.write("\n")
    else:
        pass
    num = int(num) + 1
f2.close()
```

Comment: In a bit of code you cant see, further up the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you are using a loop like

```
for one_letter in letter:
    # your code
```

to access all items of a list.

Looping with the help of an index is OK as well, but you have to stop at the right point. In your case you have 26 item and since the index is 0-based, the highest number is 25 not 26.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are indexed from 0. So the last index of your letters is 25 not 26.
But better use a for-loop, then you don't have to count by hand:

```
import string
f2 = open("Classes" + "/Sorted/" + "Alphabetical.txt", "w")
for lettername in string.uppercase:
    try:
        with open('Classes/%s.txt' % lettername) as inp:
            lines = inp.read().splitlines()
    except IOError:
        pass
    else:
        f2.write('%s - score = %s' % (lines[5], lines[6]))
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it *cleaner* and *succinct* and do it like a ninja

```
wf = os.path.join("Classes", "Sorted", "Alphabetical.txt")
rf_ = os.path.join("Classes","{letter}.txt")
line = "{} - score = {}"
# separate the output strs from logic
alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)] # ['A', 'B', ..., 'Z']
with open(wf, "wt") as fw:
    for letter in alphabet:
        rf = rf_.format(letter=letter)
        if os.path.exists(rf):
            with open(rf) as fr:
                ls = fr.read().splitlines()
                print(line.format(ls[5], ls[6]), file=fw) # this will write to fw
```

Always use `os.path.join` instead of `str` acrobatics to be robust(*Beazly*). If the code didn't work please comment.

Comment: Yes this did work thank you very much, however, im now trying to sort the data within the files and im having trouble doing that

Comment: @Banana You should update the question with your target output so that it will be clear for everyone.

Comment: I don't know how to, I've recently created an account?